# F#: Implementing interface with function name the same as the keyword begin

Tags: f#, keyword, identifier

I am trying to implement the IVector interface which is part of the Microsoft.VisualC.StlClr namespace.  It has a member function begin().  If I try to implement the interface then it complains about "unexpected keyword 'begin' in object expression".

Is this because begin is a keyword and I can't implement a member function with that name?

B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try to wrap it into backticks. IVector inteface is too big to implement it as sample, so example will be smaller - the code below compiles without any errors.

```
// C#
public interface ITest
{
    void begin();
}

// F#
type Test() = 
    interface UStatic.ITest with
        member this.``begin``() = ()
```

Comment: Would you then have to call it as `Test.''begin''` everytime? (Used quotes as can't work out how to escape backticks)

Comment: @user: Yes, you'll have to wrap the name in backticks every time you use it. It is probably a good idea to add additional member to the `Test` type that calls it and has a more reasonable name.

Comment: One more question. 

This is my implementation: 

member this.``begin``(value:byref<Generic.ContainerRandomAccessIterator<float>>) = ()

The interface definition is this:

abstract end : 
        :ContainerRandomAccessIterator<'TValue> byref -> unit 

I am getting compile error saying: "the member begin : value:byref<Generic.ContainerRandomAccessIterator<float>> -> unit does not have the correct type to override the corresponding abstract method."