# Using keywords as identifiers in F#

Tags: f#, keyword, identifier

In C#, I can do the following:

```
int @private = 15;
```

And in VB.NET, I can do the following:

```
Dim [Private] As Integer = 15
```

I am wondering if there is a way in F# to use reserved keywords as identifiers, like there is in VB.NET and C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [F#: Implementing interface with function name the same as the keyword begin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864034/f-implementing-interface-with-function-name-the-same-as-the-keyword-begin)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Given [section 3.4 of the F# 2.0 spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597387):

> Identifiers follow the specification below. Any sequence of characters that is enclosed in double-backtick marks (`` ``), excluding newlines, tabs, and double-backtick pairs themselves, is treated as an identifier.

I *suspect* you can put it in backticks:

```
``private``
```

I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Good find Jon. I tried it out by doing `let \`\`let\`\` = 75` and `System.Console.WriteLine(\`\`let\`\`)` it worked. So know we all know. Thanks for the help

Comment: This does work although it is syntactically very tedious. I recommend keeping such names private.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - I know. I agree. I am converting a library over to F# and it has an interface in it with a reserved keyword and changing the name of the interface would mean changing a bunch of other classes too, some of which, I don't have the source code. But if I could avoid it, I would. Trust me

Comment: I find this issue, but this not work with tags (F# 4.0, mono): ``Tags``  Err FS1219

Comment: @mamcx: I'm not sure how to parse that comment, I'm afraid - but perhaps this is something you should file as a bug on F#?

Comment: I mean that if using the word tags the backticks not work, it get FS1219

Comment: @mamcx: Well, I can't see an F# 4.0 specification yet - I would definitely report it to the F# folks.

Answer (score 1):

in F# 7 (FSharp.Core 7.0.0) it appears that you can add a single quote as a suffix

```
type mapping = {
    from : string
    to' : string
}
```

this allows us to use `to'` as a record property name without colliding with the keyword `to` and only requires one extra character to write and read.