# What characters are allowed in F# identifiers, module, type and member names?

Tags: f#, clr, member, naming, let-binding

This question is about characters in identifiers, not [keywords as identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639688/using-keywords-as-identifiers-in-f).

I found [this question on C# names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950616/what-characters-are-allowed-in-c-sharp-class-name), but couldn't readily find the same on F#. Normally this is hardly relevant, but in my tests naming I often use the dot `.` and was surprised it wasn't supported in a module name, but is supported in a let-binding:

```
// fails:
module ``Run Test.Me functions`` = 
    [<Test>]
    let ``X.Add should add``() = test <@ X.Add 2 2 = 4 @>

// Succeeds
module ``Run Test-Me functions`` 
    [<Test>]
    let ``X.Add should add``() = test <@ X.Add 2 2 = 4 @>
```

Outside of naming tests I don't see much use for this, but it made me wonder: what characters are supported by type and module names, and what characters for member names and let bindings?

Some tests:

```
module ``Weird.name`` = ()  // fails
module ``Weird-name`` = ()  // succeeds
module ``Weird()name`` = () // succeeds (?)
module ``Weird*name`` = ()  // fails
module ``Weird+name`` = ()  // fails
module ``Weird%name`` = ()  // succeeds (?)
module ``Weird/name`` = ()  // fails
module ``Weird\\name`` = () // fails
```

All of these name succeed in a let-binding or member name, but not as a type name or module name. At least that is consistent. But I can't find any line or logic in what is allowed and what not

Perhaps the limitation is imposed by the CLR / MSIL and not by F# itself?

Comment: @guy, I happen to have the lang spec open on my other screen, dunno why I didn't spot it. You may want to turn that into an answer, don't think it should be bad to have it here as a Q&A even if anybody can find it in the spec (but, honestly, that thing is hard to read!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [F# Language Specification 4.0](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf) - In section `3.4 Identifiers and Keywords`.

> Note that when an identifier is used for the name of a types, union
>   type case, module, or namespace, the following characters are not
>   allowed even inside double-backtick marks:
>   `.`, `+`, `$`, `&`, `[`, `]`, `/`, `\\`, `*`, `\"`, `` ` ``

In addition to this list, the `@` (at-sign) is allowed in any name, but will raise a warning:

> warning FS1104: Identifiers containing '@' are reserved for use in F# code generation

As near as I can find:

The list of characters can be found in the F# compiler with the name [IllegalCharactersInTypeAndNamespaceNames](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/PrettyNaming.fs#L547).

As this is used for generating IL, that leads to [ECMA-335 - Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) Partitions I to VI](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) which reads:

> II.5.3 Identifiers - Identifiers are used to name entities. Simple
>   identifiers are equivalent to an ID. However, the ILAsm syntax allows
>   the use of any identifier that can be formed using the Unicode
>   character set (see Partition I). To achieve this, an identifier shall
>   be placed within single quotation marks.
>
> ID is a contiguous string of characters which starts with either an
>   alphabetic character (A–Z, a–z)
>   or one of `_`, `$`, `@`, `` ` `` (grave accent), or `?`,
>   and is followed by any number of
>   alphanumeric characters  (A–Z, a–z, 0–9)
>   or the characters `_`, `$`, `@`, `` ` `` (grave accent), and `?`

Comment: Union type case makes sense: that's compiled into a type internally. My guess is this list is driven by IL limitations.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question, I just found that the `@`-sign is allowed, but will issue a warning. Just for completeness sake ;).

Comment: @Abel Feel free to edit any of my questions or answers. It is all CC and once I write it here I no longer consider it mine.

Comment: I̶t̶ ̶c̶o̶u̶l̶d̶b̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶i̶s̶s̶u̶e̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶w̶i̶s̶e̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶a̶m̶b̶i̶g̶u̶i̶t̶i̶e̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶a̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶A̶S̶T̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶E̶B̶N̶F̶.̶ strike that, it shouldn't matter, the delimiter `\`\`` is pretty definitive.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that means that the limitation is imposed and not required by ILASM, the latter allowing any unicode character according to your quote.