# How Can I Define a Record That Contains a Field named as "type"?

Tags: f#

Is there a way to define a record that contains a "type" field? For example :

```
type ProjectType= 
    | ObjectDetection 
    | Classification

type Domain =  {
    name:string;
    type: ProjectType; // How can I achieve this ?
    enabled:bool;
}
```

Comment: You can't, it's a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/keyword-reference).

Comment: @pimbrouwers Hi, as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639688/using-keywords-as-identifiers-in-f) describes, we can declare a ` ` type ` ` record.