# Is there something as C#'s @ keyword in F#?

Tags: .net, f#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using keywords as identifiers in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639688/using-keywords-as-identifiers-in-f)

C# allows you prefix your variables with the @ keyword:

> Keywords are predefined reserved identifiers that have special
>   meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your
>   program unless they include @ as a prefix. For example, @if is a legal
>   identifier but if is not because it is a keyword.

I am wondering whether there is a similar construct in F#. If I recall correctly, even VB.NET provides a similar construct.

Comment: Why would you ever want to name a variable after a keyword? It seems like that would create more confusion than it's worth.

Comment: To keep convention throughout my API. If I want to name a variable type and I can't, I may want to try ``type`` instead of a ugly t, typ, type_, or whatever.

Comment: @0x5: It's more likely that you'll have a variable is a reserved word in one language but not the one that the code was originally written in. If you need to access a library written in another language, you have to deal with this problem somehow.

Comment: This has been discussed a few times: [Using keywords as identifiers in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639688/using-keywords-as-identifiers-in-f) and [F#: Implementing interface with function name the same as the keyword begin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864034/f-implementing-interface-with-function-name-the-same-as-the-keyword-begin)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use quotes:

```
let rec ``let rec`` () = ``let rec`` ()
```